# how to save page-html with input values given, into variable on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am generating a report for which i need html of form with input values also. I am saving the form(page's HTML) with inputs given to the form into a variable. But when i save it the inputs are not coming into it.

How to save the values into it?

**HTML :**

```
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'php/processing/formInput/formDataInputProcesing.php?id=' . $_GET['id']; ?>" >
        <div id="formHtml">
        <?php echo $formHtml; ?>            
        <hr>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="formHtmlValue" name="hiddenvalue" >
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submitData" id="submitData"><i class="fa fa-check">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </form>
```

**Javascript/JQuery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#submitData').click(function(){
            var html = $('#formHtml').html();
            $('#formHtmlValue').val(html);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: your html has to have in its input tags a value atribute with the new values added

Comment: Are you sure that `$formHtml` has a value?

Comment: yes i need to have new values entered to be saved at the right place & the whole html of form to be sotred in the database so i need the final one on submit in the variable

Comment: $formHtml is just having the form's html & not values inside it

Comment: user is going to fill value in it

Answer (score 0):

I am using old method

```
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="setValue(this)" action="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'php/processing/formInput/formDataInputProcesing.php?id=' . $_GET['id']; ?>" >
    <div id="formHtml">
    <?php echo $formHtml; ?>            
    <hr>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="formHtmlValue" name="hiddenvalue" >
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submitData" id="submitData"><i class="fa fa-check">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
</form>


<script language=javascript>
     function setValue(v)
  {
  var tableContent=document.getElementById("formHtml").innerHTML;
 v.formHtmlValue.value=tableContent;
 return true;    
}
</script>
```

Comment: no. values are not coming to it. I need to catch the  form with values input by the user & not the form content only

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example:

```
   <html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="abc.php?id=123" onsubmit="setValue()" >
            <div id="formHtml">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type=text name="t1"><span id="t1Value"></span>
                        <input type=radio name="r1" value="r1" checked><span id="r1Value"></span>
                        <input type=checkbox name="c1" value="c1" checked><span id="c1Value"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            <hr>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="formHtmlValue" name="hiddenvalue" >
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submitData" id="submitData"><i class="fa fa-check">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </form>
        <script language=javascript>
            function setValue()
            {
                var formHtml=$("#formHtml");
                $("#formHtml input").each(function()
                                                    {
                                                        //console.log($(this).attr("name")+","+$(this).val());
                                                        itemName="#"+$(this).attr("name")+"Value";
                                                        $(itemName).html($(this).val());
                                                        $(this).remove();
                                                    }); 
                $("#formHtmlValue").val($("#formHtml").html());                                         
            }
        </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```